# CakePHP - all pages blank except the home page

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I inherited a very old CakePHP application (version 1.3.2) that I have to run on a new server (old server is long gone, I only have the code). I managed to get it going after some configuration and right now the home page loads here:
http://m.gratuito24.com/

So far so good, however, if you click on any of the links, absolutely nothing happens. I get no errors in the browser, no errors in the logs and I even tried to print out some debug messages from the `app_controller` `beforeFilter` and `beforeRender` methods but with no success. As you notice, the site is translated (in Bulgaria), however, using the English equivalents for the controllers and actions results in the exact same manner. Setting Debug Mode to 2 in `core.php` still displays a completely blank page.

Any idea how to approach debugging this or what might be the cause? I've looked into the `routes.php` file and there are a lot of routes set there but except for the home `'/'` route, nothing else seems to work. Basically the server is not finding a resource following the links at all which is strange as I can see that the framework/database are present thus loading the home page. Any tips appreciated.

Comment: set debug mode to 2 and try seeing for any possible errors

Comment: Forgot to mention that but I did set it to 2 and completely blank page again....

Comment: Have you checked the error log to see if any exceptions are being thrown? Also have a look and see what's happening with the routes file, as there's url rewriting going on here

Comment: As mentioned above, error log is empty. The data in the routes.php file looked ok, but just in case I removed all of it and left it empty so that pure URLs like /controller/action/ could be used. Exactly the same result, home page loads but everything else is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like a problem with mod_rewrite, look on http://m.gratuito24.com/index.php/ads/index/showAds:goods/language:bg.html, `index.php` part is important,

first thought: no mod_rewrite on server, 
second: something wrong with .htaccess

Comment: I check the mod_rewrite and it is on but it seems that it is the .htaccess file causing all the trouble after all. Still struggling with it but I'll post a different question for it. Thank you very much for your time!